# ¿Cómo puedo calcular una propiedad de un objeto de una clase en otra clase?

Tags: c#

Necesito poder calcular la casa más grande de persona1 por los metros cuadrados y ese metodo esté en la clase "Propietario" no sé como puedo hacer para que la clase propietario pueda tener las propiedades de la clase Casa, no sé si haciendo la herencia podria resolver el problema, pero al intentar hacerla me sale error por el metodo constructor de la clase Casa.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Casa casa1 = new Casa (direccion: " Calle C, No 23, Villa España", metrosC: 500 );
        Casa casa2 = new Casa (direccion: " Calle E, No 29, Villa España", metrosC: 3000) ;
        Casa casa3 = new Casa(direccion: " Hato Mayor, Las Malvinas, Calle los girasoles #45 ", metrosC: 2500);
        Casa casa4 = new Casa(direccion: "Allí", metrosC: 123);

        Propietario persona1 = new Propietario { Nombre = "Samuel", Apelliido = "De Aza" };

        persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
        persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
        persona1.AddCasa(casa3);

        foreach (Casa c in persona1.Listacasas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.IdCasa + c.Direccion + c.MetrosCuadrados + " " + persona1.CantidadCasas(persona1));
        }

    }
}
public class Casa
{
    public  int IdCasa { get; private set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int MetrosCuadrados { get; set; }

    private static int internalId;
    public Casa(string direccion, int metrosC)
    {
        this.Direccion = direccion;
        this.MetrosCuadrados = metrosC;
        Casa.internalId++;
        this.IdCasa = internalId;
    }
}

public class Propietario
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apelliido { get; set; }

    public List<Casa> Listacasas { get => listacasas; set => listacasas = value; }

    List<Casa> listacasas = new List<Casa>();
    public void AddCasa(Casa casa)
    {
        this.Listacasas.Add(casa);
    }

    public int CantidadCasas(Propietario persona)
    {
        return Listacasas.Count();
    }

    public int CasaMasGrande()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Has probado aplicando los principio de "herencia" para las dos clases ?

Comment: Ya trataste de recorrer la lista `Listacasas` con un for e ir analizando cada item la propiedad `MetrosCuadrados` e ir guardando en una variable temporal la mayor de cada comparacion. (Con linq seria mucho mas facil) pero la idea es que desarrolles la logica.

Comment: No sé como hacerlo porque al intentar hacer que Propietario herede de la clase Casa me sale error por el metodo constructor

Comment: Ohhhh buena idea, intentaré hacerlo así

Comment: Si llegas a tener algun inconveniente recorriendo la lista, lo actualizas en la pregrunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementar la interfaz [`IComparable`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c) para utilizar un método de ordenamiento que ya esté escrito. ¿Qué demonios estoy diciendo? Similar a la herencia, en lugar de *heredar* una clase vas a *implementar* una interfaz:

```
public class Casa : System.Collections.Generic.IComparable<Casa> // Igual que la herencia
{
    //... definición de tu clase y después

    public int CompareTo(Casa otraCasa)
    {
         if (this.MetrosCuadrados > otraCasa.MetrosCuadrados)
             return 1;
         if (this.MetrosCuadrados < otraCasa.MetrosCuadrados)
             return -1;
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Con esto preparas la clase para que pueda usarse dentro de un método de ordenamiento de los que ya están implementados en el lenguaje:

```
using System.Linq; // <-- Importante agregar esta línea hasta arriba del archivo

...
public class Propietario
{
    ...
    public Casa CasaMasGrande()
    {
        return Listacasas.Max(); // <-- No te preocupas por la implementación de este método,
                                 // ya viene incluido en .NET
    }

    // O bien
    public int CasaMasGrande()
    {
        return Listacasas.Max().MetrosCuadrados;
    }
}
```

Para más detalles de la función `Max()`, puedes leerte [esta guía (en inglés)](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-max/), pero básicamente lo que hace es comparar cada miembro de tu lista utilizando el método `CompareTo` que *sabe que existe* gracias a la implementación de la **interfaz** `IComparable`. Para más información sobre las interfaces, te dejo [este link (*Implementación de interfaces en C# | Let's code something up!*)](https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/implementacion-de-interfaces-en-c/).

Comment: PERFECTO! Muchas gracias, ahora lo haré

Comment: @NoobProgramer Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como "solución" para que otros que tengan un problema similar la encuentren más fácil ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modifique un poco tu código tengo Visual Studio 2015 con .NET 4.5 y c# 5.0

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Casa casa1 = new Casa(direccion: " Calle C, No 23, Villa España", metrosC: 500);
        Casa casa2 = new Casa(direccion: " Calle E, No 29, Villa España", metrosC: 3000);
        Casa casa3 = new Casa(direccion: " Hato Mayor, Las Malvinas, Calle los girasoles #45 ", metrosC: 2500);
        Casa casa4 = new Casa(direccion: "Allí", metrosC: 123);

        Propietario persona1 = new Propietario { Nombre = "Samuel", Apellido = "De Aza" };

        persona1.AddCasa(casa1);
        persona1.AddCasa(casa2);
        persona1.AddCasa(casa3);

        foreach (Casa c in persona1.Listacasas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.IdCasa + c.Direccion + c.MetrosCuadrados + " " + persona1.CantidadCasas(persona1));
        }

        // Muestro los datos de la casa más grande
        Console.WriteLine("La casa mas Grande es: " + persona1.CasaMasGrande());
    }
}

public class Casa
{
    public int IdCasa { get; private set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int MetrosCuadrados { get; set; }

    private static int internalId;
    public Casa(string direccion, int metrosC)
    {
        this.Direccion = direccion;
        this.MetrosCuadrados = metrosC;
        Casa.internalId++;
        this.IdCasa = internalId;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Id: {0}, Dir: {1}, Metros Cuadrados: {2}", this.IdCasa, this.Direccion, this.MetrosCuadrados);
    }
}

public class Propietario
{
    private List<Casa> listacasas;

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    // Esta propiedad tenia el nombre con doble i lo puse bien esta vez
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    public List<Casa> Listacasas
    {
        get { return listacasas; }
        set { listacasas = value; }
    }

    public Propietario()
    {
        this.listacasas = new List<Casa>();
    }

    public void AddCasa(Casa casa)
    {
        this.Listacasas.Add(casa);
    }

    public int CantidadCasas(Propietario persona)
    {
        return Listacasas.Count();
    }

    public Casa CasaMasGrande()
    {
        // Obtengo el valor de metros cuadrados mas grande entre todas las casas
        var maxMetro = this.listacasas.Max(obj => obj.MetrosCuadrados);
        // Obtengo la primera casa que tiene el valor de metrosCuadrados igual al valor máximo encontrado
        // anteriormente
        var maxCasa = this.listacasas.Where(obj => obj.MetrosCuadrados == maxMetro).First();
        // Retorno la casa que cumple con ese criterio
        return maxCasa;
    }

    // Si quieres solo el valor de los metros de la casa mas grande puedes hacerlo de la 
    // siguiente manera
    /*public int CasaMasGrande()
    {
        // Obtengo el valor de metros cuadrados mas grande entre todas las casas
        var maxMetro = this.listacasas.Max(obj => obj.MetrosCuadrados);
        // Obtengo la primera casa que tiene el valor de metrosCuadrados igual al valor máximo encontrado
        return maxMetro
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias man, buena explicación.